# how to merge xml string to main xml document object

Tags: c#, xml

how can i merge the following xml string

```
<employee>
    <name>cliff</name> 
</employee>
```

to my existing xml document object

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement xmlCompany = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Company");
```

the final output should look like

```
<Company>
 <employee>
    <name>cliff</name> 
 </employee>
</Company>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the InnerXml property of your company Element:

```
string xmlString = "<employee><name>cliff</name></employee>";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement xmlCompany = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Company");
xmlCompany.InnerXml = xmlString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XLinq APIs

```
    XElement existing = XElement.Parse(@"<employee> 
                                             <name>cliff</name>  
                                         </employee>");
    XElement newElement = new XElement("company", existing);
```